# Why are development style sheets and devise logout not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, stylesheet

I have a 3.2.8 Rails application which has been deployed into production and is running just fine.  While preparing to code an enhancement I pulled fresh code from the SVN and started up a development version of the application and found the stylesheets were non functional and the Devise logout did not work in DEVELOPMENT.

All other aspects of the application work exactly as they should.

I've been reading many stack over flow Q & A and cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Then I realized the default version of Ruby did not match the version for the application.
The application was built with ruby 1.9.3 p286  and my machine boots up in Ruby 2.1.0

solution:
stop the server

rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p286

bundle install

rails server

= good to go.